# Compilation issue while creating object oriented linked list (compiler error C2664)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list

I'm writing a class, embedding a reversible linked list, and I'm having trouble with the type of the null pointer:

Linked list definition:

```
struct LL {
  int information;
  LL* pre;
  LL* succ;
  };
```

Class definition (partially):

```
class T_LL {
  private : 
    LL  *lList;
    int index;
    int size;
  public :
    T_LL() {
      lList = new(LL);
      lList->pre = nullptr;
      lList->succ = nullptr;
      size = 0;
      index = -1;
    }
  ...
    LL get_successor(){
      if (index+1 <= size) {
        return *lList->succ;
      } else { return nullptr; }
    }
```

When I try to compile this, the compiler complains about the `get_successor()` method, saying:

```
error C2664: 'LL::LL(const LL &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'nullptr' to 'const LL &'
```

I thought that the nullpointer was a general pointer, which can be used for any purposes? What am I doing wrong (and why is there no compilation error in the constructor)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated to your question: your design is poor because it embeds "current index" within the list. Also, your index calculations seem to be off by one.

Comment: (1) I can see that. The point is that the class **should not** take care of the index in any shape or form. (2) How doed it work out for an empty list? `index` is -1, `size` is 0, `index+1<=size` is true.

Comment: Oops: `index+1<size` :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_successor()` returns a value of type `LL`.  It cannot return a pointer.  You may want to change it:

```
LL* get_successor(){
  if (index+1 <= size) {
    return lList->succ;
  } else { return nullptr; }
}
```